# How do I re-use a color value throughout a storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am using storyboard to lay out my iOS app. I want to re-use some colors, and I don't want to re-enter the same hex string multiple times. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag the current color in the color picker (from the bottom left) to the list of swatches as in the screenshot:

[image]

You can also use the dropdown for picking a color to use a recent color. The list of recently used colors looks like it keeps 24 of them.